# Populating array with items from another array throws TypeMismatch Error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, types

for belows code the line `vItemsNotInMaster(k) = vCheckItems(i)` throws a type mismatch error once the array `vItemsNotInMaster` shall be populated. I am not sure why - as the caller sub and function array variables are all declared as `Variants` and types did not change according to the Locals Window.

I tried different data types but, this does throw other error messages.

```
Public Sub Testing()
Dim myArray1(1 To 4) As Variant
Dim myArray2(1 To 4) As Variant
Dim myArray3 As Variant

   myArray1(1) = "one1"
   myArray1(2) = "two3"
   myArray1(3) = "three5"
   myArray1(4) = "four7"

   myArray2(1) = "one1"
   myArray2(2) = "two3"
   myArray2(3) = "different"
   myArray2(4) = "four7"
   
   myArray3 = Comparing_TwoArrays(myArray1, myArray2)
   Stop
End Sub

Public Function Comparing_TwoArrays(ByVal vCheckItems As Variant, ByVal vMasterList As Variant) As Variant

   Dim vItemsNotInMaster As Variant
   Dim isMatch As Boolean
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   Dim k As Integer
   
   ReDim vArray3(1 To UBound(vCheckItems, 1) + UBound(vMasterList, 1))
   k = 1
   
   For i = LBound(vCheckItems, 1) To UBound(vCheckItems, 1)
       isMatch = False
       
       For j = LBound(vMasterList, 1) To UBound(vMasterList, 1)
           If vCheckItems(i) = vMasterList(j) Then
               isMatch = True
               Exit For
           End If
       Next j
       
       If (isMatch = False) Then
           vItemsNotInMaster(k) = vCheckItems(i) '---> Throws type mismatch
           k = k + 1
       End If
   Next i
   
   If (k > 1) Then
      ReDim Preserve vArray3(1 To k - 1)
   Else
      vArray3 = Empty
   End If
   
   Comparing_TwoArrays = vArray3

End Function
```

Does someone has an idea?

Code Example credited to: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/comparing.htm

Comment: `vItemsNotInMaster` is not an array. Replace every instance of `vArray3` with `vItemsNotInMaster`

Comment: Strange piece of code, looks very unfinished. What is the idea of `Comparing_TwoArrays`, what do you want to return?

Comment: @Rory - Okay, I added `ReDim Preserve vItemsNotInMaster(1 To k)` before the `vItemsNotInMaster` is populated which did the trick for the aforementioned error.

Comment: @FunThomas - Just using the code snippet as a starting point - it shall return the items as a list, that are different between two arbitrary long lists/arrays.

Comment: but the routine will always return an array without data - `vArray3` never gets any data. It looks to me as if `vArray3` is superfluent and you should use `vItemsNotInMaster`  at the end of the code. Surprised that such piece of code could make if to a page called *betterSolutions*

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you need to replace **every** instance of `vArray3` with `vItemsNotInMaster`, not just one.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and fix all the notifications about not declared variables!

Comment: If you replace `vItemsNotInMaster(k) = vCheckItems(i)` with `vArray3(k) = vCheckItems(i)`, it will work. It is a mistake in the code. And, of course, delete `vItemsNotInMaster` declaration, which is there by mistake, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, replacing `vItemsNotInMaster(k) = vCheckItems(i)` with `vArray3(k) = vCheckItems(i)` will solve the problem.

But if you need learning arrays manipulation, the next more compact code returns the same in less code lines number:

```
Public Sub Testing_()
Dim myArray1(1 To 4) As String
Dim myArray2(1 To 4) As String
Dim myArray3 As Variant

   myArray1(1) = "one1"
   myArray1(2) = "two2"
   myArray1(3) = "three5"
   myArray1(4) = "four7"

   myArray2(1) = "one1"
   myArray2(2) = "two3"
   myArray2(3) = "different"
   myArray2(4) = "four7"
   

   myArray3 = Application.IfError(Application.match(myArray1, myArray2, 0), "x") 'it palces "x" when not a match...
   Debug.Print Join(myArray3, "|") 'just to visually see the return...
   'for a single case:
   Debug.Print "(first) missing element: " & myArray1(Application.match("x", myArray3, 0)) 'it returns according to the first occurrence
   
   'For more than one missing occurrence:
   Dim i As Long
   For i = 1 To UBound(myArray3)
        If myArray3(i) = "x" Then
            Debug.Print "Missing: " & myArray1(i)
        End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

To return occurrences independent of array elements position, it is also simpler to use `Application.Match` (with a single iteration). If interested, I can also post such a function...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @FunThomas the function does not return anything. Fix for type mismatch error is to Redim the  `vItemsNotInMaster` array for each new item, while preserving the already populated values.

The vArray3 variable does not make sense and function should be rewritten as:

```
Public Function Comparing_TwoArrays(ByVal vCheckItems As Variant, ByVal vMasterList As Variant) As Variant

   Dim vItemsNotInMaster()
   Dim isMatch As Boolean
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   Dim k As Integer
   
   
   k = 1
   
   For i = LBound(vCheckItems, 1) To UBound(vCheckItems, 1)
       isMatch = False
       
       For j = LBound(vMasterList, 1) To UBound(vMasterList, 1)
           If vCheckItems(i) = vMasterList(j) Then
               isMatch = True
               Exit For
           End If
       Next j
       
       If (isMatch = False) Then
           ReDim Preserve vItemsNotInMaster(1 To k)
           vItemsNotInMaster(k) = vCheckItems(i) '---> Throws type mismatch
           k = k + 1
       End If
   Next i
   
   
   Comparing_TwoArrays = vItemsNotInMaster

End Function
```

Comment: Note that the original solution of defining a big array and then reduce the size once in the end as the OP did it was much better! Using `ReDim Preserve vItemsNotInMaster(1 To k)` many times in the loop costs a lot of processing time. You do not want to use it in a loop. Use `ReDim Preserve` as less as possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Return Matching Array Elements

- The function will return an array of the not matching elements from the check array in the master array.
- If all elements are matching (are found in master), it will return an array whose upper limit is less than its lower limit.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Testing()
    
    Dim myArray1(1 To 4) As Variant
    Dim myArray2(1 To 4) As Variant
    Dim myArray3 As Variant
    
    myArray1(1) = "one1"
    myArray1(2) = "two3"
    myArray1(3) = "three5"
    myArray1(4) = "four7"
 
    myArray2(1) = "one1"
    myArray2(2) = "two3"
    myArray2(3) = "different"
    myArray2(4) = "four7"
   
    myArray3 = NotInMasterArray(myArray1, myArray2)
   
    If LBound(myArray3) <= UBound(myArray3) Then
        ' Column
        Debug.Print "Column" & vbLf & Join(myArray3, vbLf)
        ' Delimited row:
        Debug.Print "Row" & vbLf & Join(myArray3, ",")
    Else
        Debug.Print "All elements from Check array found in Master array."
    End If
   
   Stop
End Sub

Public Function NotInMasterArray( _
    arrCheck() As Variant, _
    arrMaster() As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ResultLowerLimit As Variant) _
As Variant()
   
    ' Write the check array's limits to variables.
    Dim cLB As Variant: cLB = LBound(arrCheck)
    Dim cUB As Long: cUB = UBound(arrCheck)
    
    ' Determine the lower limit ('nLB') of the result array.
    Dim nLB As Long
    If IsMissing(ResultLowerLimit) Then ' use the check array's lower limit
        nLB = cLB
    Else ' use the given lower limit
        nLB = ResultLowerLimit
    End If
     
    ' Calculate the result array's upper limit.
    Dim nUB As Long: nUB = cUB - cLB + nLB
    ' Define the initial result array ('arrNot') making it the same size
    ' as the check array (it is possibly too big; it is only of the correct size,
    ' if all check array's elements are not found in the master array).
    Dim arrNot() As Variant: ReDim arrNot(nLB To nUB)
    ' Write the result array's lower limit decreased by 1 to the result
    ' array's limit counter variable (to first count and then write).
    Dim n As Long: n = nLB - 1
    
    Dim c As Long ' Check Array Limit Counter
    
    ' Loop through the elements of the check array.
    For c = cLB To cUB
        ' Check if the current element is not found in the master array.
        If IsError(Application.Match(arrCheck(c), arrMaster, 0)) Then
            n = n + 1 ' count
            arrNot(n) = arrCheck(c) ' write
        'Else ' found in master; do nothing
        End If
    Next c
    
    If n < nLB Then ' all found in master
        arrNot = Array() ' i.e. UBound(arrNot) < LBound(arrNot)
    Else ' not all are found in master
        If n < nUB Then ' not all elements are not found...
            ReDim Preserve arrNot(nLB To n) ' ... resize to 'n'
        'Else ' all elements are not found; do nothing
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Assign the result array to the result of the function.
    NotInMasterArray = arrNot
    
End Function
```